# getSpeechRate()? (or how to tell what rate TTS is currently set at)

Tags: android, text-to-speech

[TextToSpeech](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) has a way to set the speech rate: [setSpeechRate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setSpeechRate%28float%29). But it doesn't have an opposite method of querying the current speed.

Is there a way to query **the system** for that value?

Comment: Since the rate is per-instance, and assuming that you have access to the TextToSpeech instance for which you're interested in the speech rate, couldn't you keep track of every time that you change the rate (it should be 1.0 before you change it)? Or are you concerned about the override setting that causes rate changes to be ignored? Perhaps you could read the shared preferences for com.google.tts ?

Answer (score 1):

You may get default TTS speech rate

```
Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.TTS_DEFAULT_RATE, 100) / 100f;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for similar thing and it seems like there really isn't such a method. But since [1.0 is the normal speech rate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setSpeechRate%28float%29), I solved it by keeping the rate in my own variable. I have a class that provides few methods to work with TTS, so here's my implementation:

```
public class MyTts {
    private static float rate = 1.0f;
    ...


    public float getSpeechRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    public int setSpeechRate(float rt) {
        rate = rt;
        return tts.setSpeechRate(rate);
    }
    ...
}
```

Where `setSpeechRate` returns `TextToSpeech.ERROR` or `TextToSpeech.SUCCESS` according to documentation.

**Edit:** Seems like when I set rate to i.e. 1.5f and then back to 1.0f it's not the same. It depends on tts settings in Android.