# android TextToSpeech: getting the audio time length

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm working in android using the **TextToSpeech** class and Have a string with and specific length. I want to calculate the estimated time of this generated text to speech audio (I know that i can get the audio and then get the time length of this generated audio but I want to explore other alternatives).

I'm trying getting the **speechRate** (but seems no posible) and the with the length of the String create some formula getting as result an estimation of the time.

Any sugestions??

Thanks in advance.

PD: About the spechRate: [getSpeechRate()? (or how to tell what rate TTS is currently set at)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954874/getspeechrate-or-how-to-tell-what-rate-tts-is-currently-set-at)

Comment: There is no accurate way to do this without actually rendering the speech.

Comment: You can create a mp3 file and get its length. I think this is the easy way.

Answer (score 1):

I use int pauseInSeconds=1+string.length()/7 for short english speaking.

Very rough of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
private void speakWord(String word)
{
     //Get time
     textToSpeech.speak(...);
     checkSpeaking(true);
}

private void checkSpeaking(boolean isSpeaking)
{
    Print.e("Speaking is: " + isSpeaking);
    if (isSpeaking)
    {
        new Handler().postDelayed(()-> 
        {
            if (textToSpeech.isSpeaking()) {
                checkSpeaking(true);
            }
            else {
                checkSpeaking(false);
            } 
        },300);
    }
    else
    {
        //Get time
    } 
}
```