# how to get tts speech rate for Android?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

We can set speech rate using the setSpeechRate function. 
But I don't know how to get speech rate from TTS.

if you any idea or solution, Please share your knowledge. Regards.

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no way to do this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954874/ for some potential work arounds.